# string manipulation - re.sub in jython

Tags: jython, text-manipulation

Let say i have a string like this  'this is a statement'
and if i want to search and replace string with this  'this ** a statement'

string to search for  this is a statement , this si a statement , this i a statement and any combination convert them into   this **trim** a statement 
i.e for any *word combination* between this & a statement replace it with *trim* 
for another set  replace *fun* to *notfun* .

### so this is the program

```
import re
file=open('file','r+')
search=re.sub('this \(a_zA_Z0_9)+ a statement','\1trim',file),('this is fun','this is notfun',file)
file.close()
```

something is not right as nothing is getting changed in the file.

thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.sub` doesn't work on files, it works on strings.  You need to read the contents of the file into a string, then use re.sub to change the string, then write the modified string back to the file.

A simple example:

```
text = open("myfile.txt").read()
# This is your original re.sub call, but I'm not sure it really does what you want.
text = re.sub('this \(a_zA_Z0_9)+ a statement', '\1trim', text)
text = re.sub('this \(a_zA_Z0_9)+ another replacement', 'some other thing', text)
open("myfile.txt", "w").write(text)
```

Comment: can you please show me with the above example ,how can i do that . 

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Ned , actually that was my main question , as how can i have two different string replaced so 

re.sub('this \(a_zA_Z0_9)+ a statement', '\1trim', text),re.sub('this is fun','this is notfun',file)

so in short can two re.sub work in a single line or not ? if not how to accomplish this part.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: There's no need to do both replacements in one line, simply call re.sub twice as I've edited the answer.  Don't forget to accept it if it works for you! :)